# JsonSerializer Deserialize string error - invalid primitive

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I read the other questions that were liken to this one and they were not the same.

I am trying to get this value into a string property:

```
{
    "Save": {
        "InArguments": [
            {
                "ArgumentName": "Id",
                "Value": "UVE1NjFGdVVFZU95OWdCUVZvZGc1Zzo1MDow"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Property is Id - the value should be "UVE1NjFGdVVFZU95OWdCUVZvZGc1Zzo1MDow"

The class has this property:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

I have other dataTypes in this class, Collections and bools and they get Deserialized just fine. What is it about this value that it doesn't like? I tried making it Lower case, thinking the format was bad - no go. What this value contains is an encrypted Id.

Here is how I am getting the particular item I want in the json within the InArguments class:

```
 public new T Get(ActivityContext activityContext)
    {
        var item = activityContext.DataContext.Arguments.Find(r => r.ArgumentName.ToLower() == ArgumentName);

        try
        {
            if (null != item)
            {
                if (null != item.Value)
                {
                    Type argumentType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
                    var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    return (T)jsSerializer.Deserialize<T>(item.Value.ToString());                        
                }
                else
                {
                    return default(T);
                }
            }

            return default(T);
        }                
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log exception
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

The ArgumentType returned is a String. Exactly what dataType the Property it is trying to populate is.
The Get method is called during the initializing of my object I want to get:

```
var sendDefinitionRestHandler = new SendDefinitionRestHandler()
            {
                Id = Id.Get(activityContext)
 };
```

Hope this is enough info, let me know if you need me to elaborate on anything. Thank you for the time.

Comment: This is true. I added the extra data to allow it to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this is the answer to my particular problem. The 'Value' was not being handled as a string going into the Deserializer. So it was bombing on the 'U' and gave me the Primitive error.

By simply adding a single quote around the Value:

```
"Value": "'UVE1NjFGdVVFZU95OWdCUVZvZGc1Zzo1MDow'"
```

It was able to Deserialize it into a string. This should not have been a problem to begin with, at least I don't think it should. Now I am trying to figure out what it cares and why it wouldn't view it as a string to begin with.